# How to convert a byte array to an int array?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm using a dsPic33F (16 bit microcontroller);

- How to convert `char[]` to `int[]` such that every two chars becomes an int using C++?
- and the inverse operation?

Comment: Do you want to simply change the type of each element without modifying any values (that is, for every `i`, `byteArray[i] == intArray[i]`) or do you need to reinterpret the `byte` array as an `int` array (e.g. 4 consecutive `byte` elements → 1 `int` element)?

Comment: I suppose you mean `int` to `char` ?

Comment: @In silico. Each pair of bytes will be converted to a single int

Comment: @wilhelmtell I think you are right. I always mix `byte` and `char`

Comment: Do you need big or little Endian?

Comment: What arrangement of chars you want to have in int?

Comment: @Brian I don't know if this MCU is big or little endian

Comment: @Jader, I advice study programming model for this MCU, if you want to code for it. This helps you understand ho to do such tasks. And, dsPIC33F is little endian (lower byte is at lower address). But if you do not have to do arithmetic calculations on combined ints, it does not matter.

Comment: C++? does the dsPic33F has c++ support? You using the C30 compiler right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int* intArray = new int[sizeOfByteArray];

for (int i=0; i<sizeOfByteArray; ++i)
   intArray[i] = byteArray[i];
```

Or

```
std::copy(byteArray, byteArray+sizeofByteArray, intArray);
```

Comment: You need to clarify the problem first.  N bytes -> N ints?  if not this fails.  Pointer arithmetic would be better than indexing also.

Comment: Well, he said byte[] to int[], so I assumed a 1:1 correspondence (otherwise it's just a cast). Yes, I'd probably use pointer arithmetic or just std::copy, but if someone doesn't know how to copy an array, I don't want to obfuscate the operation.

Comment: What if I needed to get an int of every 2 bytes?

Comment: If `sizeof(int) == 2`, then `int* intArray = (int*) byteArray;` would do it.

Comment: Never use `new[]`. Use `std::vector`. There's no loss, only gain.

Comment: @GManNickG, No. This is not C++, this is embedded C, the land of the `free()` and home of the `malloc()` & `memcpy()` (brave).

Comment: @ahogen: Looks like OP edited the tags after I commented. What an old comment!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to combine packs of bytes into int?

what you need to do is to shift the bits when you create your int

(oki this is java because I don't have my C ++ code here)

```
public static final int byteArrayToInt(byte [] b) {
    return (b[0] << 24)
            + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
            + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8)
            + (b[3] & 0xFF);
}

public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
}
```

this logic works with any conversion formats as long as you know the length of your variables

Comment: @user440336 I understand your solution. I would have to adapt it to 16 bit integers

Comment: knock out the 24 then ^^ if you get the logic then you can use this code for converting from any to any format. glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

On a dsPIC 33F, I doubt you're using C++.  If you are using C++, what compiler are you using, and how much of a runtime library do you have? (And where did you get it!)

If the byte ordering is correct, you can just use memcpy() if you need a copy, or just cast the pointer if you just want to use the 16 bit numbers in the buffer and the alignment is OK. If you are managing the buffer, it is not unusual to use a union for this kind of requirement on a platform like this:

```
union my_buffer {
    unsigned char char_buf[128];
    int int_buf[64];
};
```

Access through char_buf when dealing with characters, access through int_buf when dealing with ints.

If the bytes need to be swapped, just implement a variant of swab() and use it instead of memcpy(), something like the other answers, or some code like this:

```
void doit(int16_t* dest, char const* src, size_t word_count)
{
    char* const end = (char*) (dest + word_count);
    char* p;

    for (p = (char*) dest; p != end; src += 2, p += 2) {
        p[0] = src[1];
        p[1] = src[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong. This will work on your PC, but will not on dsPIC. Be aware of CHAR_BIT value!

Comment: +1 I feel the -1 is unjustified Again "How to convert char[] to int[] such that every two chars becomes an int using C++"

Comment: @vovanium: Wrong. dsPIC 30/33 has 8 bits per byte, and so has CHAR_BIT defined as 8. If CHAR_BIT wasn't 8, then there wouldn't even be an int16_t type.

Comment: @janm: int16_t type will be if integer type of exactly 16 bits exits, and does not matter is it a char or short or int. And question was for int, not int16_t. But you shold be care of CHAR_BIT anyway, especially you're programming a DSPs.

Comment: @janm but you're definitely right about dsPIC detail, i've missed this while looking in datasheet.

Comment: @vovanium: Yes, I agree, on a platform where CHAR_BIT is 16, an int16_t type can exist. We agree, however, this isn't that platform.

Comment: Platform and compiler, you mean. :)

Comment: @janm So maybe I'm using `C` and not `C++`, is that what you mean? I'm not sure which language this is. I'm sure however that I don't use many `C++` features.

Comment: @Jader Dias: Yes, that is what I mean. I'm pretty sure you're using C on that platform, but if you are using C++, I'm interested to know about the compiler. In general though, I find it useful to know what language I'm using when writing code!

Comment: @janm you're right, [mplab](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en019469&part=SW007002) uses a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your byte mean char or octet. You may have octets already packed by two in dsPIC's 16-bit words so you have no more to pack them.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define BYTE_BIT CHAR_BIT /* Number of significant bits in your 'byte' * Read note below */

/* pack routine */
void ipackc(int *packed, const char *unpacked, size_t nints) {
    for(; nints>0; nints--, packed++, unpacked += 2) {
        *packed = (unpacked[0]<<BYTE_BIT) | (unpacked[1] & ((1<<BYTE_BIT)-1));
    }
}

/* unpack routine */
void cunpacki(char *unpacked, const int *packed, size_t nints) {
    for(; nints>0; nints--, packed++, unpacked += 2) {
        unpacked[0] = *packed>>BYTE_BIT;
        unpacked[1] = *packed & ((1<<BYTE_BIT)-1);
    }
}
```

That's a C code, but there's nothing to deal with C++ features. It compilable in C++ mode. You may replace limits.h and stddef.h with climits and cstddef for tighter C++ conformance.

- Note: This code will not work if 2 your 'bytes' cannot fit into int. Check this. Number of bits in int should be not less that 2*BYTE_BIT or one of chars will be lost. If you mean 8-bit octet under 'byte', you may change CHAR_BIT in BYTE_BIT definition to just 8, and then 16-bit int will fit octets correctly.

Note about implementation:

```
((1<<BYTE_BIT)-1)
```

is a bit mask for N lower bits, where N=BYTE_BIT. It equal

```
    /--N--\
...011...11 (binary)
```

Comment: (unpacked[1] & ((1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1)) is all a bit pointless; just declare it as (or cast to) unsigned char to avoid sign extension.

Comment: @janm: If char is wider than CHAR_BYTE bits, then this have a sense. I understand that THIS DSP have 8bit char, but this is not general case. Reason I wrote this I already explained.

Comment: @vovanium: Type "char" can never be wider than CHAR_BIT bits, it will always be CHAR_BIT bits wide. That is the meaning of CHAR_BIT.

Comment: @janm: Oops, i mean BYTE_BIT, which is defined in my code snippet. User may redefine it to 8 while CHAR_BIT is 16. For the case CHAR_BIT==BYTE_BIT this line is useless though

Comment: @vovanium: Yes, but then you're dealing with an aspect of the data, rather than an aspect of the platform/compiler, and it's best not to mix these things up.

Comment: That's why i defined another macro of BYTE_BIT, to deal with 'BYTE' rather than compiler defined value. User may decide is his byte is really char or octet and define this appropriately. Code would work in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that your char array contains bytes (instead of actual ascii characters), which you want to convert into 16-bit signed integers.  The function below will work for MSB-first byte ordering.  I used unsigned chars here to represent the byte input (uint8_t).

`void BytesToInts(uint8_t *byteArray, uint16_t byteArraySize, int16_t *intArray, uint16_t intArraySize) {`

```
    //do some error checking on the input
    if (byteArraySize == 0) return;
    if (intArraySize != (byteArraySize/2)) return;

    //convert each pair of MSB-first bytes into a signed 16-bit integer
    for (uint16_t i=0; i<intArraySize; i++)
    {
        intArray[i] = (int16_t) ((byteArray[i<<1]<<8) | byteArray[(i<<1)+1]);
    }
```

}

If you need the integer definitions, you can use something like this:

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef signed short int16_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
```

Comment: Note, author said about **DSP**, which in general may have any number of bits in char (possibly 16), so you should be careful: use CHAR_BIT macro instead of 8, test if int is enough to store two chars (2<=sizeof(int)).

Comment: +1 @ Vovanium Again He did say:"How to convert char[] to int[] such that every two chars becomes an int using C++" IE two chars will fit into a int

Comment: @vovanium: dspic 33F has eight bits per byte.

Comment: @janm, i never stated that dsPIC's char is other than 8 bit (but also not stated that it IS 8 bit). Read carefully.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a compiled and tested method:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short ByteToIntArray( 
        unsigned char inByteArray[], 
        unsigned short inArraySize, 
        unsigned short outWordArray[], 
        unsigned short outArraySize, 
        unsigned char swapEndian
    )
{
    if (    ( inArraySize/2 > outArraySize )
         || ( outArraySize == 0 ) 
         || ( inArraySize == 0 )
       )
    {
        return -1;        
    }

    unsigned short i;

    if ( swapEndian == 0 )
    {    
        for ( i = 0; i < outArraySize; ++i )
        {
            outWordArray[ i ] = ( (unsigned short)inByteArray[ i*2 ] << 8 ) + inByteArray[ i*2 + 1 ];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < outArraySize; ++i )
        {
            outWordArray[ i ] = ( (unsigned short)inByteArray[ i*2 + 1 ] << 8 ) + inByteArray[ i*2 ];
        }
    }
    return i;    
}


int main(){
    unsigned char ucArray[ 16 ] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF };
    unsigned short usArray[ 8 ];
    unsigned short size;

     // "/ 2" on the usArray because the sizes are the same in memory
     size = ByteToIntArray( ucArray, sizeof( ucArray ), usArray, sizeof( usArray ) / 2, 0 );

    if( size > 0 )
    {
        printf( "Without Endian Swapping:\n" );
        for( unsigned char i = 0; i < size ; ++i )
        {
            printf( "0x%04X ", usArray[ i ] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    if( size > 0 )
    {
         // "/ 2" on the usArray because the sizes are the same in memory
        size = ByteToIntArray( ucArray, sizeof( ucArray ), usArray, sizeof( usArray ) / 2, 1 );

        printf( "With Endian Swapping:\n" );
        for( unsigned char i = 0; i < size ; ++i )
        {
            printf( "0x%04X ", usArray[ i ] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The *ByteToIntArray* takes 5 parameters and returns the size of the actual converted array, this is handy if you pass in *outWordArray* that is bigger then the actual converted size and at the same time serves as a way to pick up errors.

A simple bit-wise shift operator and + is used for combining the two bytes into one word.

I just used printf to test the procedures and I'm aware that to use this in embedded hardware usually takes allot of code space.  And I just included Endian swapping to make sure you can see what you need to do in both cases but this can easily be removed in your actual implementation.

There is also lot of room for optimization in the *ByteToIntArray* routine but this way it is easy to understand.

Comment: Test it on dsPIC before. There's nothing common between PC and dsPIC's chars, shorts ant ints.

Comment: @Vovanium He edit ask Using C++ "How to convert char[] to int[] such that every two chars becomes an int using C++" but hey such is live.

Also put a -1 infront of the comment to state that it is the reason for the -1

Comment: On dsPIC 33 with the MPLAB C30 compiler, char is 8 bits, int is 16 bits, and sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) == 2.

Comment: True, but this is a detail and does not indulge programmer from using system limit constants. Note, author did not wrote aabout compiler he use.

Comment: Sure, portable code is a Good Thing™. However, once we're into byte swapping we've started to move data between platforms and we need to consider things beyond the specific platform being targeted.